# Monotouch Async and showing Activity Indicator

Tags: asynchronous, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I've got the following code being called in view the viewdidload method inside of my UIViewController.

Inside the appdelegate I have a UINavigationController which is instantiated with this aforementioned controller and in turn the UINavigationController is placed inside a UITabViewController which in turn is assigned as the rootviewcontroller.

Inside the controller I'm making an async web call to get the data to populate a table, if I use the loading view code to display an activity indicator I get the following warning in monotouch.

**Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**

```
public class LoadingView : UIAlertView
{
    private UIActivityIndicatorView _activityView;

    public void ShowActivity (string title)
    {
        Title = title;

        this.Show();
        // Spinner - add after Show() or we have no Bounds.
        _activityView = new UIActivityIndicatorView (UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge);
        _activityView.Frame = new RectangleF ((Bounds.Width / 2) - 15, Bounds.Height - 50, 30, 30);
        _activityView.StartAnimating ();
        AddSubview (_activityView);

    }

    public void Hide ()
    {
        DismissWithClickedButtonIndex (0, true);
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

EDIT : I'm already setting the root view controller.

```
window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        window.RootViewController = tabController;
```

Full appDelegate code :

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            tabController = new UITabBarController();

            jobsNavigationController = new UINavigationController(new JobsController());
            jobsNavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
            jobsNavigationController.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/briefcase.png");
            jobsNavigationController.TabBarItem.Title = "Current Positions";

            myAccountNavigationController = new UINavigationController(new LoginDialogViewController());
            myAccountNavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
            myAccountNavigationController.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("images/man.png");
            myAccountNavigationController.TabBarItem.Title = "My Account";

            tabController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { jobsNavigationController,myAccountNavigationController,new SettingsDialogViewController()},false);

            window.RootViewController = tabController;

            // make the window visible
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible (); 
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the FinishedLaunching method in the AppDelegate? This is where that error is usually thrown. In iOS 5 you are required to assign the RootViewController, ex: window.RootViewController = MyTabBarController;

Comment: Take a look now, already doing what you suggest.

Comment: Please post your complete FinishedLaunching(). My best guess is that your tabConroller is NULL.

Comment: Will do as soon as I get home, although the tabController is instantiated as a member level variable. To get rid of the error all I need to do is remove the call to Loadingview.ShowActivity.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this warning (in iOS5) and keep iOS 4.x compatibility you can do the following inside your `FinishedLaunching` method:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (5, 0))
    window.RootViewController = navigation; 
else
    window.AddSubview (navigation.View);
```

Look [here](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/Sample/Main.cs#L82) for a more complete sample.

Comment: window.RootViewController is already available in iOS4, so that cannot be the problem.

Comment: @Krumelur IIRC Apple shows that warning (the problem) only on iOS5+ but you're right it's been available since iOS4, so you can simply assign it without the condition.

Answer (score 0):

window.AddSubview(tabcontroller.view);

Fixed the issue, odd I don't set the rootviewcontroller anymore.